# Requiring Listbox Selection for userform

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
whichSheet = ListBox1.Value
Dim n As Integer
Do
n = n + 1
ListBox1.AddItem Sheets(n).Name
Loop Until n = Worksheets.Count

Worksheets(whichSheet).Activate
Dim lastrow
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrow = lastrow + 1
Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1
answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")
If answer = vbYes Then
Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Text
Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox3.Value
Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox4.Text
Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox5.Text
Cells(lastrow, 6) = TextBox6.Text
Else
    Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ListBox1.AddItem (ws.Name)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Hello guys, I am using the code above which works perfectly for my userform. The only issue I'm having is that when someone doesn't pick a choice from the listbox1 and submits the info, the "Runtime Error" window pops up. I would like to stop that from happening by making a message box appear that tells users to make a choice--->click ok on the message box---> and then resume. If the user doesn't select an option still the same procedure should occur every time. If you have any ideas, I would love to try them out. Thanks.

Comment: If you can proceed without errors if there's not a choice, you can add `On Error Resume Next` right before that choice is made/used in your macro. Then after that, reset the error handling with `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I spent some time trying to incorporate your suggestion but I was having trouble getting it to work still.The On Error Resume Next portion open a message box that wouldn't close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred way of handling this situation is to disable `CommandButton1` if nothing in the `ListBox1` is selected. Or, in other words, enable the button when something is selected.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    CommandButton1.Enabled = False  ' <--- here.
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ListBox1.AddItem (ws.Name)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I don't have Excel open at the moment, but you want a corresponding listbox event to enable/disable the button. The following is an example and untested.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    CommandButton1.Enabled = ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1
End Sub
```

Another approach is to check to see if something has been selected when you enter the `CommandButton1_Click` routine and handle it there. But I prefer to prevent bad user input in the first place - less complicated.

Comment: This one works perfectly; your suggestion was right on the money. Thanks AJD

Comment: I want to do the same for each textbox (1,2,4,5,6) and require them to be filled out before the CommandButton1 is enabled. I have tried the following:          
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    CommandButton1.Enabled = Len(TextBox1.Text) >= 3
End Sub                                                                                                        I haven't had any luck though.

Comment: @sway: post a new question. A similar technique, but a slightly more complex answer because more than one TextBox is involved. And with more than one control a slightly more sophisticated technique.